# Shell script in Python subprocess.Popen does not terminate child

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, popen

I have an issue with interrupting the `subprocess.Popen` This is the setup:

I have a Tkinter gui and it is running a another python script using the `Popen`. This inner script (let's call it `running script`) is running a shell shell script that is executing a piece of C++ code using a `Popen` so the hierarchical structure is looking like this:

```
GUI
\running_script
 \shell-script
  \c++
```

`running_script` works so that if it receives an interrupt, it sends SIGINT to `shell-script`. If i run a `shell_script` with my piece of C++ code with the `running_script` alone and do a CRTL+C everything works like a charm. However if i do it with GUI running the `running_script` as Popen, SIGINT is sent to the `running_script` is receives it properly and sends the interrupt signal to `shell-script`, but instead of terminating the inner process(being c++ code), the `shell-script` terminates itself and the C++ process continues running, as it was ran in the background, but it was not. When I execute `ps -xaf` the tree looks like this:

```
GUI
\running_script
 \shell-script <defunct>
c++
```

So to reiterate, when i run it without the GUI it works like a charm, but with GUI it behaves as explained above. I've tried sending `shell-command` a SIGTERM instead of SIGINT as well, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could catch SIGINT in the shell script and make it send SIGINT to the c++ program, e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
./cpp_program &
procpid=$!
function killit() {
    kill -SIGINT $procpid
}
trap killit SIGINT
......
```

Comment: Hey @hir12111 thanks for the response. Unfortunately this is not a solution i can work with, tho i had it in mind. The reason is that there are over 1000 shell scripts and they are being added every day by a large team, and the team is not willing to change their process just to fit one auxiliary python app. I would instead like to know why is SIGINT propagated without the GUI and not when the GUI is active.